# How to create char[][] from String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I got a little problem here with Java and I am fairly new to it.

My program reads a String via `InputStreamReader` and saves it in the String `input`.

How do I  save the elements of the String in a 2d char array with n x m elements?

Edit:
I think I´ve got a solution:

I used 2 for-loops (is that the right english translation for it? ) and .toCharArray to convert the String.

```
public static char[][] transform (String text, int arrBreite, int arrLaenge) {
    char[][] returnArray = new char[arrBreite][arrLaenge];

    char[] buffer = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrBreite; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <arrLaenge; j++) {
            if (((i * arrBreite) + j) > buffer.length - 1) returnArray[i][j] = " ".charAt(0);
            else returnArray[i][j] = buffer[(i*arrBreite)+j];
        }
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Have you read the JavaDoc for String?

Comment: For what reason do you need a 2d array of chars?

Comment: Please provide an example how you want chars to be placed inside your `char[][]`?! Giving input and a matrix how it should look like after work is done.

Comment: There's no natural mapping from a String to a 2d character array. What exactly are the requirements here? How do you know what the dimensions of your 2d array are?

Comment: I´ve to do a Scytale De-/Encrypter and we should use an 2D Array for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method to get a `char` array from your `String`.

If you need to split with a given delimiter to determine the array lines, you use first the [`Split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method on the `String`, then use `toCharArray` to create your 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).